# Couldn't add the Keychain Item. Error - 25299 after change the identifier with KeychainItemWrapper?

Tags: ios, keychain, keychainitemwrapper

I wanna save UUID in keychain with KeychainItemWrapper, so I add the following methods in **MyKeychainManager.m** :

```
#define keychain_idenentify @"com.myapp.bundle1"

+ (void)saveUUID:(NSString *)UUID{
  if([MyKeychainManager getUUID].length > 0) {
    return;
  }
  KeychainItemWrapper *keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc]initWithIdentifier:keychain_idenentify accessGroup:nil];
  [keychain setObject:UUID forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrLabel];
}

+ (NSString *)getUUID {
  KeychainItemWrapper *keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc]initWithIdentifier:keychain_idenentify accessGroup:nil];

  NSString *uuidString = [keychain objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrLabel];
  return uuidString;
}
```

But after I change the **keychain_idenentify** to **com.otherApp.bundle**, it crashed at

> result = SecItemAdd((CFDictionaryRef)[self
>   dictionaryToSecItemFormat:keychainItemData], NULL);       NSAssert( result
>   == noErr, @"Couldn't add the Keychain Item." );

and the error is **Error - 25299**

Why is this and how to solve this? Which I should choose such as **kSecAttrLabel**? I changed it to **kSecAttrService** it works fun but I don't know is there any other potential bugs.

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 5):

This error means that an item with this identifier already exists (https://osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-25299). Try deleting it from the keychain and then your code should work.

Answer (score 2):

I've spent a lot of days in struggling the same problem. At last , I'v found the cause of it that I pass by too easily.

That is an important constant of keychain. Take a look at the codes.
(Assuming that I used keychain in my target for the first time)

```
KeychainItemWrapper *test1 = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"test10"  accessGroup:nil];
[test1 setObject:(id)@"value1" forKey:(id)kSecValueData];
//Normally it works

KeychainItemWrapper *test2 = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"test20"  accessGroup:nil];
//At this point , we meet the crash with the message of 'Couldn't add the Keychain Item.'
[test2 setObject:(id)@"value2" forKey:(id)kSecValueData];
```

Even if the name of 'initWithIdentifier' is different , the constant 'kSecAttrAccount' must be unique.
Its default value is ""( that is empty). Once keychain wrapper is used , the 'kSecAttrAccount' of it is saved . So you need to pay much attention to the 'kSecAttrAccount' when you use the another 'initWithIdentifier'.

I can fix the crash of above codes by adding some codes.

```
    KeychainItemWrapper *test1 = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"test10"  accessGroup:nil];
[test1 setObject:@"test1" forKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
[test1 setObject:(id)@"value1" forKey:(id)kSecValueData];

KeychainItemWrapper *test2 = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"test20"  accessGroup:nil];
[test2 setObject:@"test2" forKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
[test2 setObject:(id)@"value2" forKey:(id)kSecValueData];
```

For more information, if you use the accessGroup of KeychainItemWrapper,
as I mention above , the kSecAttrAccount must be unique regardless of using accessGroup or not.

The following is an example.

```
KeychainItemWrapper *test = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"test"  accessGroup:"App_ID.SampleName"];
```

As you know , App_ID should be created at the apple developer and SampleName should be setup at the capabilities of KeyChain Sharing of your app target.
The '.' between App_ID and SampleName must be added. This is a key point.

Please refer to the postings the other persons uploaded about how to set it.