# Unable to read value from Keychain iOS

Tags: swift, keychain

Trying to implement/learn keychain use in iOS. I have saved multiple values of a struct in Keychain but while retrieving values it is showing nil. Testing the code in **Simulator** only. This is the generic keychain read method:

```
        extension KeychainHelper{         
        func read<T>(service: String, account: String, type: T.Type) -> T? where T : Codable {
        // Read item data from keychain
        guard let data = read(service: service, account: account) else {
        return nil
        }

         // Decode JSON data to object
        do {
            let item = try JSONDecoder().decode(type, from: data)
            return item
           } catch {
           assertionFailure("Fail to decode item for keychain: \(error)")
           return nil
        }}}
```

The full code of KeychainHelper class can be found here [full keychainhelper class](https://gist.github.com/LeeKahSeng/2452e90a57a5324de367907a36d88a49) (can be replicated easily)
when I am calling the API the code is working fine showing values also

```
         class ViewModel : ObservableObject{
          
          //some published var like centerService
          
          let token = response.ResponseData.AuthToken
          //other var
          
           let userDetails = Pass(authToken:token, other vars)
           KeychainHelper.standard.save(userDetails,service,account)
         }
```

But when I am trying to read keychain from different func it is showing nil. This is the call:

```
     class checkStatus{
        var userStatus = ViewModel()  
        let userDetails = KeychainHelper.standard.read(service: userStatus.centerService, 
        account:userStatus.centerAccount, Pass.self)
              }
```

The error is Operation failed with status -25299. Pass definition:

```
     struct Pass:Codable{
      let authToken:String
      let centerID:String
      let userID:String
      let accessID:Int
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

This error means that an item with this identifier already exists: [OSStatus codes](https://osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-25299) Try deleting it from the **keychain** . You can also check other answers in [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54899998/couldnt-add-the-keychain-item-error-25299-after-change-the-identifier-with-k)

Comment: deleted than again saved the credentials same issue finished with status -25299 it means save func is working correctly but not read.... why it is failing to read it I dont want to write again and again...once it is stored it should be readable

Comment: Did the deletion of keychain item ended with succcess status code? Anyway, I don't personally like apple keychain API, so If you don't mind adding another dependency into your project, I can only recommend using  [Keychainswift library](https://github.com/evgenyneu/keychain-swift) which is more easy to use and user friendly. (and no need to use unsafe swift)

Comment: yes status was 0.....all values, which I am trying to save and read, returned nil on first run after that same prob unable to read....this is frustrating

Comment: and trying this form of saving password? : [DAKechainn class](https://github.com/dagostini/DAKeychain/blob/master/DAKeychain/Classes/DAKeychain.swift)